# Accessing index and item of list by enumarte in loop

Tags: python

I have a nested list like this

```
   list = [[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
```

Where each index of the first list represents a score of sum of 1's. For index 0 the score is 1, for index 1 the score is 2 and for index 3 the score is 3.

In the nested list, each position of the index where there is a 1 represents an addition to the score. The addition in the score is equal to the score with the same position as where the 1 is found in the first of the 2 nested lists.

If in the second of the nested lists the position of the 1 is in index position 0 and 2 like in index 1 in the first of the nested lists, the score increases by 1 + 3.

What I am trying to do is write a single or nested loop that adds all the scores from simply the sum of scores, then add the additional scores.
Something like

```
    for i, k in enumarate(list):
      score = sum(k)
      score += sum(k[i])
```

Comment: What would be the expected score for the example? `11` like `6*1 + (0) + (0+2) + (0+1+2)`

Comment: no pattern in the sub lists

Comment: Scores would be: 2, 6 and 6

Comment: @AlejandroFuentes how is that `[1,0,1]`,`[1,1,1]` are different lists but yet their scores are the same? (6 and 6)

Comment: Because the second list gets 2 first, then +1 and +3. The thirs list gets first 3 then +1 +2 +3 (sorry) my mistake

Comment: @AlejandroFuentes Doesn't that make 9 for the third list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using a list comprehension:

```
alist = [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

for i, k in enumerate(alist):
    score = sum(k)
    score += sum([index + 1 for (index, item) in enumerate(k) if item == 1])
    print(score)

2
6
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list = [[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
intermediate = [sum(i)+sum(c*(d+1) for d, c in enumerate(i)) for i in list] #for demonstration purposes
print(intermediate) #[2, 6, 9]
final_data = sum(sum(i)+sum(c*(d+1) for d, c in enumerate(i)) for i in list)
```

Output:

```
17
```

Note that @schwobaseggl was correct when he pointed out that the score for the final list is 9, because according to the OP's logic, the last sum should be 3 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 9.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption that the scores as you describe them in the comments should be 2, 6 and 9, you could do the following:

```
lst = [[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]
scores = [sum(l) + sum(x*sum(y) for x, y in zip(l, lst)) for l in lst]
# [2, 6, 9]
```